# How are assets assessed for criticality?

Tags: risk-management

Following on from [the post regarding risks assessments](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81451/risk-assessment-scope-and-critical-assets) and critical assets, how are assets assessed for criticality be it infrastructure, processes, people (possibly), etc?

If using the security triad of confidentiality, integrity and availability, are these the only factors that define criticality?

How does one calculate the cost of the associated risks? For example, if the business deems a given set of assets as high across the entire triad, how does one determine the impact, costs and risks?

Comment: Depends on your organization. CIA is a beginning but there are other assets - reputation, business function, etc.  Most risk management guides suggest that you establish the asset categories early in the process (confusingly, they call them "categories")

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace - Thanks. Is there a starting list i can leverage? Secondly, if i needed the ability to cycle through these quickly to ascertain criticality, what's the best way since every project is now deemed "agile" and security is seen as slowing down the "agility"? I would like to be able to manage the perception and process but deliver the risk profile to management as quickly as possible.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - The post at http://www.bloginfosec.com/2010/08/23/why-the-risk-threats-x-vulnerabilities-x-impact-formula-is-mathematical-nonsense/ doesn't recommend the use of the formula Risk = Threat x Vulnerabilities however others in the post such as "Henry" suggest an approach which i believe will resonate with management.

Comment: Nontrivial questions.  I don't have a starting list - I argue against starting lists because selecting that list is a critical part of the process; risk management is about the discussion/process, not the goal. 2) Security is a non-functional requirement like all other nonfunctional requirements. If requirements impede your agility, then you  are pursuing a dangerous path.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of R=TxV - that formula generates more argument than solutions.   Risk = (Likelihood x Impact )/control is better. Best is to collect data for a year and then figure out what formulas make sense.  That isn't always practical, so I suggest that you concentrate on analyzing the risk and proposing mitigation.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace - Considering the maturity of the organization, starting lists may prove to be valuable in that they provide guidance while knowledge and maturity evolves. I agree on security being non-functional requirements however given the maturity of the organization and its practices, attempting to do this without showing tangible value and speed, is a futile attempt. Non-functional requirements have only been introduced recently since there wasn't a comprehensive "list" to start with which i have had to develop from the ground up.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - How would you calculate likelihood and impact? For example, i came across https://binary.protect.io/#tools. If i look at the assessment, the questions are broad and often non-intuitive. For instance, does the asset have significant value? What is value? Financial, Reputation, Legal, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If using the security triad of confidentiality, integrity and
>   availability, are these the only factors that define criticality?

While the CIA triad is important to us as security professionals when defining various criteria, the business often defines severity levels based on $$$.

They ask questions (from a business perspective) such as:

- What infrastructure / applications do we need in place to accept money
  from customers? (think POS systems)
- What infrastructure / applications do we need in place to *move* money? (think wire/ACH systems)
- How much money do we lose per day if XYZ application is not available?
- Are there operations / processes that can be completed manually (paper, pen) until the systems are back online?

> How does one calculate the cost of the associated risks? For example,
>   if the business deems a given set of assets as high across the entire
>   triad, how does one determine the impact, costs and risks?

This is where your quantitative and / or qualitative analysis comes into play from a risk perspective.

Below are a few good links that cover the formula in detail:

http://www.pearsonitcertification.com/articles/article.aspx?p=418007&seqNum=4

http://www.sans.edu/research/leadership-laboratory/article/risk-assessment